# Introductory book on Gromov Witten Theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking for a good introduction to Gromov Witten Theory. I have a background in algebraic geometry, which corresponds roughly to the first three chapters of Hartshorne.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I really like the book [An Invitation to Quantum Cohomology](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817644567). It focuses exclusively on genus zero GW invariants for simplicity but it requires very little background and constructs the space of stable maps in full details with very nice exercises along the way.

The goal of the book is to develop as much GW theory and quantum cohomology to prove Kontsevich's formula for the number of degree $d$ rational curves through $3d - 1$ points in the plane. I think its a good starting point to then go on and learn more of the general theory.

I also have to mention Fulton and Pandharipande's [Notes On Stable Maps and Quantum Cohomology](http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9608011v2.pdf) which is more advanced but is the classic introduction to the field.